# Appending to a string (created in base class) in derived classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

So this is a rather specific question.

Assuming I have a set of classes, which all generate a different string. The only thing in common between these, is that they require the same "header" in the string.

I have decided to create a base class for generating the header, which they all derive from.

```
internal abstract class StringBase
{
    public virtual string WriteString()
    {
        var headerString = "header";
        return headerString;
    }
}
```

Now for a derived class, which must include the header, but also add its own subsequent string.

```
internal class DerivedString : StringBase
{
    public override string WriteString()
    {
        var derivedString = // How would I best add the header and append more to it?
        return derivedString;
    }
}
```

Overriding it like this would obviously overwrite whatever the base `WriteString()` does, so how would I make sure I get it? Could it be something like adding a non-virtual method in the base, which then calls the virtual method with the header string as a parameter?

```
internal abstract class StringBase
{
    public void WriteHeader()
    {
        var headerString = "header";
        WriteString(headerString);
    }

    public virtual string WriteString(string headerString)
    {
        var derivedString = headerString.Append("whateverString");

        return string.empty;
    }
}

internal class DerivedString : StringBase
{
    public override string WriteString(string headerString)
    {
        var derivedString = headerString.Append("whateverString");

        return derivedString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) keyword for this, like so:

```
internal class DerivedString : StringBase
{
    public override string WriteString(string headerString)
    {
        var derivedString = base.WriteString().Append("whateverString");

        return derivedString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it work is by using a private field in base class:

```
internal abstract class StringBase
{
    private string headerString = "header";
    public virtual string WriteString(String input=null)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? headerString : headerString + input;

    }
}
```

and then you can call the method from derived classes by passing in the parameter.